# Write in file after an expression

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have this file and regex :

```
$pattern = '/.*services {1,}:/';
$services = file_get_contents($services_file);
preg_match($pattern, $services, $matches);
dump($matches)
```

I was able to find my expression in the file now I want to write something right after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace()`.  The `$0` is the full match to the pattern and adds your `$replacement` text after it:

```
$result = preg_replace($pattern, "$0$replacement", $services);
file_put_contents($services_file, $result);
```